What theorems can we prove using Turing Machines and the currently known Busy Beaver numbers? (2024)
Preface When BB(5) was determined recently, I got really excited. I understand how easy it would be to prove a certain collection of theorems if we knew all the busy beaver numbers. For example, for some natural number n (I forgot which) there exists an n-state Turing Machine that halts if and only if the Riemann Hypothesis is false, in particular, if and only if the machine halts before BB(n) steps. This means the machine will either halt and we can stop waiting for it to halt, or after running for BB(n) steps we would know the machine would never halt and we can stop waiting for it to halt. While not very enlightening, either outcome would imply the truth value of the Hypothesis in finite time.
My question is for n $\leq 5$, what are the theorems for which we know

There exists an n-state Turing machine that halts if and only if the theorem is true/false,
How to construct the Turing Machine in 1.?

What efforts have been made to catalogue the theorems we know are included in the answer? Feel free to include answers for Turing Machines with more than 1 symbol, tape, etc. (so long as the corresponding busy beaver number is known).

What theorems can we prove? Nothing. Five states is far too small to build a mathematically interesting Turing machine with.

@TonyK I am not very familiar with the list of 5-state machines and what they do. How did you arrive at the conclusion, "Five states is far too small to build a mathematically interesting Turing machine with?"

By contrast, I am very familiar with the list of 5-state machines, having spent a large part of 2023 collaborating with the project that finally proved that BB(5)=47,176,870. Broadly speaking, all these machines can do is count, and the only question is how much they can count up to. If you want to prove a real theorem using Turing machines, you need to program a machine to perform proof checks or something equally difficult.

BTW, the current situation is that you need more than 100 states but less than 1000 states to construct Turing machines whose halting status would decide interesting mathematical statements. The exact number for the Riemann Hypothesis was 744 the last time I looked (but progress is constantly being made). Needless to say, running a Turing machine for BB(744) steps is not a viable approach.
